# How to rewrite the value of a certain element in a nested list in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested, url-rewriting

```
M = [[3.5, 1.0, 9.2, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 8.0, -2.0]]
c_idx = 2
for count4 in range(len(M)):
    for count5 in range(len(M[count4])):
        if M[count4].index(M[count4][count5]) == c_idx :
            M[count4] = M[count4][ :c_idx] + [0] + M[count4][c_idx+1 : ]
        count4 += 1
    count5 += 1
print(M)
```

So I'm trying to rewrite an element of a certain position for the list,M. But it shows me an error:

```
if M[count4].index(M[count4][count5]) == c_idx :
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The result should be like this:

```
[[3.5, 1.0, 0, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 0, -2.0]]
```

I don't see where i'm doing wrong. Help me out folks!

Comment: Can you explain/show what your expected result is?

Comment: [[3.5, 1.0, 0, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 0, -2.0]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `count4 +=1` and `count5 +=1`

```
M = [[3.5, 1.0, 9.2, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 8.0, -2.0]]
c_idx = 2
for count4 in range(len(M)):
    for count5 in range(len(M[count4])):
        if M[count4].index(M[count4][count5]) == c_idx :
            M[count4] = M[count4][ :c_idx] + [0] + M[count4][c_idx+1 : ]

print(M)
[[3.5, 1.0, 0, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 0, -2.0]]
```

`for/loop` in `range` already did `+=1` for you.
There are much cleaner approaches mentioned in other answers, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replaceElement(l, index, element):
    for row in l:
        row[index] = element
    return l

M = [[3.5, 1.0, 9.2, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 8.0, -2.0]]
c_idx = 2
M = replaceElement(M, c_idx, 0)

>>> M
[[3.5, 1.0, 0, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 0, -2.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
M = [[3.5, 1.0, 9.2, 4.0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3.0, 1.0, 8.0, -2.0]]

c_idx = 2
for sublist in M:
    sublist[c_idx] = 0 # change the third element to 0 in each sublist
print(M)
```